# Can't embed message in message due to autogenerated pointer

Tags: pointers, go, struct, protocol-buffers

I have the following 3 protobuf messages.

```
message Item {
    uint32 ID = 1;
    string Name = 2;
    ...
}

message ItemIdsRequest{
    string batchUUID = 1;
    repeated uint32 itemIds = 2;
}

message ItemsResponse{
    string batchUUID = 1;
    repeated Item items = 2;
}
```

A function retrieves a list of item ID's to later fetch all its details. These ID's are stored in the mssage `ItemIdsRequest` along with a `batchUUID` for aggregating via event-sourcing.

Then a function retrieves all details as a `[]messages.Item` from the int slice in `messages.ItemIdsRequest`. I copy the `batchUUID` from the message `ItemIdsRequest` over into the `message.ItemsResponse`.

But when I try to copy the returned `[]messages.Item` into belows message I get the error `cannot use items (type []messages.Item as type []*item)`

```
// returns []messages.Item
itemsPB, _ := api.getItems("", items.ItemIds...)

itemsResponse := &messages.ItemsResponse{
    BatchUUID: uuid.NewV4().String(),
    Items:   itemsPB,
}
```

I cannot change the function to the following, because the item is a pointer, not the slice of items which the function returns. And I cannot have the functions return 'message.ItemsResponse'.

**TLDR**: I have two seperate protobuf structs. I am trying to set the `[]messages.items` in the `messages.ItemsResponse` `items` property but I am not allowed to because the generated protobuf code makes the `messages.ItemsResponse` `items` property a pointer. When I edit the autogenerated code and remove the pointer... everything works as intended.

```
type ItemsResponse struct {
    BatchUUID            string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=batchUUID,proto3" json:"batchUUID,omitempty"`
    Items                []*Item  `protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=items,proto3" json:"items,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}
```

I am new to protobuf and no expert on pointers (wanting to be) so I could also use some help understanding why its autogenerated into a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf [documents that](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#repeated) for repeated message fields the generated Go code will use a slice of pointers. This allows optional values, because in Go structs cannot be `nil`, but pointers can.

If you have a slice of structs and you want to assign that to a variable or field which is a slice of pointers, you have to "manually" produce that value.

Use a simple loop to do that:

```
// returns []messages.Item
itemsPB, _ := api.getItems("", items.ItemIds...)

itemPtrs := make([]*messages.Item, len(itemsPB))
for i := range itemsPB {
    itemPtrs[i] = &itemsPB[i]
}

itemsResponse := &messages.ItemsResponse{
    BatchUUID: uuid.NewV4().String(),
    Items:     itemPtrs,
}
```

Note that the slice of pointers we assemble above points to the elements of the original `itemsPB` slice.

If you modify `api.getItems()` to return a slice of pointers (`[]*messages.Item`), you could assign that without having to create a slice of pointers.